# Implementing RateLimit in Asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, rate-limiting

I am supppose to implement rate limit in my legacy mvc application. I could see some ##ratelimiting## libraries available on nuget packages but which supports .net core latest versions. But I am worried about installing it for my old project. I tried to implement this pacakge **RateLimit** but my application does not work as expected, may be I would have committed mistake. Can someone share your ideas or links to overcome this issue, as I am suppose to resubmit my project for security audit. Thanks in advance.